# How to change the color of a screen cell directly in termnal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I know i can use escape sequence like `\e[31;41m` to change the color of following output to terminal. But how to change the color of a screen cell directly? I need it in the  following two cases:

- I want to go back(through cursor-moving escape sequence) and dye a character already existed on screen.
- I want to make a screen cell colored only and hope no characters contained in it.

I know in the old days of 0xb8000 i can do this, but in *nix terminal I can't find a way.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI terminals operate at a much lower level, which (among other things) lets them work across the network. Generally, you want to run a buffer on *top* of the output stream, so you can remember what character was in that cell and write it again with the new color.

Note also that there is a VT400 code, DECCARA, that allows changing *non*-color attributes (bold etc), but it is not widely supported. Just use a buffer.